# Testing a WCF Service

Tags: wcf

I have a few questions about setting up and running a WCF service after done coding it.

I've created my service. I'm able to right-click it in VS and choose to run it in the browser and it comes up.

Now I want to test tie service by creating a new C# project and adding a service reference to my service (`.svc`).

When I try to add the service reference it can't find it (e.g. `http://localhost:55129/Cars.svc`).

So do I need to have my service project running in order to add it?

And would I need to set it up in IIS? Or are people mainly running it from within VS, running the WCF project itself?

Here is the error I get when trying to add that service endpoint:

> There was an error downloading `http://localhost:55129/Cars.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata`.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: `http://localhost:55129/Cars.svc`.
>   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service `http://localhost:55129/Events.svc`. The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>   The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the development web service, it has to be running for you to generate client proxies.

Hosting in IIS is more convenient in this respect as it is always running even if you don't have your solution open.

Comment: that's what I figured.  Also I think I need to to get the Svcutil.exe and create a client object so I can essentially test the WSDL...right?

Comment: That's what I do but maybe there are other ways.

Comment: doesn't seem like I even need that Svcutil.exe, I guess it's just to create a config file for the client.    After referencing the service from within another C# project, the generated wsdl seems to create a serviceclient for you for whatever service you're referencing

Comment: Yes, svcutil is a command line tool to do the same thing as adding service references from VS.